# On refresh, the route goes to home page using react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

whenever I click on refresh the route is going on the homepage, for all other situations it is working fine. Can someone suggest how to handle this case? I am using react router v5 and routing is done like this

```
    <Route exact path="/home">
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path={['/', '/shipments']}>
      (
        <ShipmentList />
      ) : (
        <PageNotFound />
      )}
    </Route>
```

Comment: What URL is shown in the browser, when clicking refresh?

Comment: What does "click on refresh" mean exactly? What is the home page, `"/home"` and `Home` component? Is that expected? What are "for all other situations" where it's working fine? What are the exact steps to reproduce this issue? Also, what is going on with the code in the second route? That doesn't appear to be valid syntax. Can you edit the post to include a [mcve]?